# Set Powershell window on remote computer to insert, not overwrite

Tags: windows, powershell, remote-desktop

This is a strange, annoying problem.  Perhaps someone knows how to fix it.

I'm on a windows 8.1 computer (HERE) using RDC to remote into another windows 8.1 machine (THERE).  Every time I access the RDC window on HERE, the powershell window on THERE Insert mode is set to overwrite.  Pressing insert on my keyboard will change the mode to insert.  Note: this only happens with the powershell window, all other places where I can type are insert by default (command prompt, browser windows, ide's etc).

If, on HERE, I lose focus on the RDC window to do something locally, then go back to the RDC session, the powershell insert mode will be reset to overwrite.  I haven't closed any THERE's powershell window, not have I closed the RDC window on HERE.

This is driving me cray-zee.

(does anyone ever actually use overwrite mode????)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably want to go to the PowerShell properties on THERE to make sure the Edit Options are set to 'Insert Mode'. You can get to the properties by clicking the PowerShell icon in the top left corner of the window, assuming you're in Desktop mode.

Comment: Ah that was it!  Thank you so much :)

Comment: If you run powershell from a cmd.exe (e.g. when connecting via SSH), you also need change the cmd.exe defaults and set "Insert Mode" there. The procedure is the same as for Powershell: Open a cmd.exe, right-click the title and change the setting in "Defaults".